# Android soft menu overlaps screen

Tags: android, material-design, nexus-5

I have a RelativeLayout and a floating button at the bottom. The problem is that in devices with api 21 or above the soft menu overlaps the green button and only see a half button. It does not occur with other devices.

[image]

Comment: Please post more info, like the theme you are using.

Comment: Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar (support library). So it has an actionbar and tabs.

Answer (score 2):

Finally I got the solution! Add this to your `themes.xml` in a values-v21 dir:

`<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">false</item>`

Comment: This will remove statusbar color from activity.

Answer (score 1):

Get Navigation bar height and set padding bottom to the root layout of your activity in OnCreate() after setContentView.

```
.....
        int navHeight = getNavHeight();
        if (navHeight > 0) {
            (findViewById(R.id.rlMain)).setPadding(0, 0, 0, navHeight);
        }
.....

    private int getNavHeight() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
            return 0;
        try {

            Resources resources = getResources();
            int resourceId = resources.getIdentifier("navigation_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
            if (resourceId > 0) {
                boolean hasMenuKey = ViewConfiguration.get(getApplicationContext()).hasPermanentMenuKey();
                boolean hasBackKey = KeyCharacterMap.deviceHasKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK);

                if (!hasMenuKey && !hasBackKey) {
                    return resources.getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return 0;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that worked for me was adding fitsSystemWindows into the global theme style:

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>
    </style>
```

And in the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:name=".App">
    ...
```